# Show / Hide child UL on anchor click

Tags: jquery

I am creating a tree in HTML with child nodes ...

I need to show/hide an UL when the A tag on the same LI is clicked.

In the following example, the UL containing 3.1 and 3.2 should show/hide when the A tag with 3 is clicked.

```css
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $("ul").toggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">3</a>
   <ul> 
     <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
   </ul>          
</ul>
```

Note: At the moment I am using "a" on click but it should be only the A tags that have a UL on the same LI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//bind only on the 'a's that have a sibling 'ul'
$("a").filter(function(){
    return ( $(this).siblings('ul').length > 0 );
}).on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide sibling ul element (if it exists)
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Finding the parent and again drilling down to the children is definitely an inefficient move.

Comment: You could do siblings and find the ul.  I would simply avoid next() as your relying on position at that point.

Comment: Don't I need to restrict only  to A tags that have a simbling UL and add preventDefault only for those ones?

Comment: Ok, modified to only bind on the a tags that have a sibling ul element, and also prevents default. (note: the last comment about toggling if the ul exists is mute as the filter ensures that one will exist).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.next()` at this context to achieve what you want,

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9frpr6jq/)

Comment: Don't I need to restrict only  to A tags that have a simbling UL and add preventDefault only for those tags?